# Wso2 ESB twitter connector not working

Tags: wso2-esb

I have created sample project for wso2 twitter connector by referring documentation. [Twitter Connector Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Twitter+Connector#TwitterConnector-getTopTrends)

The proxy configuration as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="twitter-connector-proxy"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="enable"
       trace="enable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target> 
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="INIT" value="************ init proxy *************"/>
         </log>
         <twitter.search configKey="twitter_init">
            <search>cricket</search>
         </twitter.search>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="RESULT" value="***************** Twitter Search Result ***************"/>
         </log>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence/>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

And the local entry as follows

```
<twitter.init xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
      <consumerKey>***</consumerKey>
      <consumerSecret>***</consumerSecret>
      <accessToken>***</accessToken>
      <accessTokenSecret>****</accessTokenSecret>
</twitter.init>
```

I also imported the Twitter certificate to ESB client keystore. When I test the proxy I am getting the following error log.

```
2015-08-25 14:16:47,679 Executing fault handler mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator   More
    2015-08-25 14:16:47,677 FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler  More
    2015-08-25 14:16:47,676 Suspending endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint - last suspend duration was : 30000ms and current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Tue Aug 25 14:17:17 IST 2015   More
    2015-08-25 14:16:47,675 Endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed  More
    2015-08-25 14:16:47,674 FaultHandler : AnonymousEndpoint    More
    2015-08-25 14:16:47,674 ERROR_EXCEPTION : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem    More
    2015-08-25 14:16:47,673 ERROR_DETAIL : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem   More
    2015-08-25 14:16:47,672 ERROR_MESSAGE : Error in Sender More
    2015-08-25 14:16:47,671 ERROR_CODE : 101500 More
    2015-08-25 14:16:47,027 INIT = ************ init proxy *************    More
    2015-08-25 14:10:55,951 Successfully created the Axis2 service for Proxy service : twitter-connector-proxy
```

Comment: Perhaps are you behind a corporate proxy / firewall ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this proxy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="twitter_search"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence onError="faultHandlerSeq">
         <property name="consumerKey" expression="json-eval($.consumerKey)"/>
         <property name="consumerSecret" expression="json-eval($.consumerSecret)"/>
         <property name="accessToken" expression="json-eval($.accessToken)"/>
         <property name="accessTokenSecret" expression="json-eval($.accessTokenSecret)"/>
         <twitter.init>
            <consumerKey>{$ctx:consumerKey}</consumerKey>
            <consumerSecret>{$ctx:consumerSecret}</consumerSecret>
            <accessToken>{$ctx:accessToken}</accessToken>
            <accessTokenSecret>{$ctx:accessTokenSecret}</accessTokenSecret>
         </twitter.init>
         <twitter.search>
            <search>Cricket</search>
         </twitter.search>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

And send the request body as follows:

```
{
  "consumerKey":"xxxx",
  "consumerSecret":"xxxx",
  "accessToken":"xxxx",
  "accessTokenSecret":"xxxx"
}
```